# How to obtain server response from AngularJS controller - flow.js

Tags: angularjs, flow-js

I am calling an API and posting an image to server using flow.js.
I am making this call from AngularJS controller:

```
    <div flow-init flow-file-added="!!{png:1,gif:1,jpg:1,jpeg:1}[$file.getExtension()]">
         <button ng-click="sender($flow)">send Image</button>
    </div>


    $scope.sendImage=function(flow)
    {
        flow.upload();

    }
```

The image is successfully received by the server, however I have searched on the internet about how to obtain the server response within the `sendImage` function
but I couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late but this is how I'd do it...

```
<div flow-init 
     flow-file-added="!!{png:1,gif:1,jpg:1,jpeg:1}[$file.getExtension()]" 
     flow-file-success="success($file, $message)">
    <button ng-click="sender($flow)">send Image</button>
</div>


$scope.success = function($file, $message) {
    $file.msg = $message;
    console.log('resp', $message);
}
```